# My join fails when it should work

Tags: mysql

This is just a simple join, but why is this failing?

```
  "id"  "borrowMax" "holder"    "category"  "country"
  "1"   "2"         "0"         "10"        "US"
  "2"   "0"         "1"         "0"         "US"
```

I'm actually trying to combine these two sqls into one.

```
select id, holder from mytable where id = 2
select borrowMax from mytable where id = (holder from the above select) and category = 10
```

**How I'm doing it**

```
SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax
FROM collection_db col1
JOIN collection_db col2
ON col2.holder = col1.id
WHERE col1.id = 2 //2 = Value supplied by me
AND col2.category = 10
```

Result i'm trying to get:

```
"id"    "holder"    "borrowMax"
"2" "1" "2"
```

Comment: I get no error. Only a blank row.

Comment: Can you use a nested SELECT instead of a join with itself?

Comment: Why do you even need a join here? Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Why not select id, holder, borrowMax from mytable where id = 2 and borrowMax = id and category = 10?

Comment: Can you explain what is failing? Do you get wrong results, do you get an error message?

Comment: I get no rows at all. 0 rows returned. No other error messages. However, this worked:but is the correct `SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax
FROM collection_db col1
INNER JOIN collection_db col2
ON col1.holder = col2.id
WHERE col1.id = 2
AND col2.category = 10;
`

Comment: @PiLHA They are 2 diff statements. The value of holder from the first is passed to the second sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you just have the table names the wrong way round when giving the column names on the JOIN ON clause:-

SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax
FROM collection_db col1
JOIN collection_db col2
**ON col1.holder = col2.id**
WHERE col1.id = 2 //2 = Value supplied by me
AND col2.category = 10

Comment: Flipping the table names makes it work. Thats all thats need to be done right? `SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax FROM collection_db col1 JOIN collection_db col2 ON col1.holder = col2.id WHERE col1.id = 2 AND col2.category = 10;`

Comment: Yep. Your original query took the 2nd row in alias col1, and then used the id of it (2) to try and match another row which contained that value in the column holder. As there was no such row and it is an inner join that meant no rows were returned. What you really seemed to want was the match the row in alias col2 which has an id was was the same as the value in holder for the row in alias col1.

Answer (score 2):

I think result is correct

```
col2.holder = col1.id will give 

"id"  "borrowMax" "holder"    "category"  "country"
 1         ....     1  ...........................
```

Then another condition on this is `col1.id = 2`

Here no record with `2`.So you are not getting any records

Comment: @jmenezes did you understand my answer

Comment: Umm... I did. I update my question with the result i'm trying to get.

Comment: This works, but is this the right way to do it? `SELECT col1.id, col1.holder, col2.borrowMax
FROM collection_db col1
JOIN collection_db col2
ON col1.holder = col2.id
WHERE col1.id = 2
AND col2.category = 10;`

Comment: i think with this you can not get the output whatever you said